# Set registry key in VBS

Tags: vbscript, registry, wsh

So my problem starts off with me trying to clear my screen in cscript. I want to make a clock program, but I want it so you don't need to set a registry key to use it.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "CONSOLE\VirtualTerminalLevel"
objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath
```

Right now, I think that this is the only way to set a registry key.
(if this helps im trying to set CONSOLE\VirtualTerminalLevel to dword=00000001)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I believe you want to call **objRegistry.SetDWORDValue**, not **objRegistry.CreateKey**.  Alternately, you could simply use `With CreateObject("WScript.Shell") : .RegWrite "HKCU\CONSOLE\VirtualTerminalLevel", 1, "REG_DWORD" : End With` in your VBScript without involving WMI.  HTH.

Comment: this actually worked! at first i couldn't understand how it worked, but now i know. thank you so much.